# Why fail in request with Alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift, ssl, alamofire

I want to get data of github/users, then i try two methods:

The first method is succesful:

```
AF.request("https://api.github.com/users").responseJSON { response in
    print("UOUOUOUOUOU", response.description)
}
```

But with the second it fails, why?

```
Network.request(Request.users).responseDecodable { (response: AFDataResponse<UserList>) in
      switch response.result {
      case .success(let value):
        print("SUCCESS")
      case .failure(let error):
            print("FAIL")
      }
    }
```

I need to use the second method.

This is my class Network

```
class Network {
  let session: Session
  let evaluators = ["api.github.com/users": PinnedCertificatesTrustEvaluator(certificates: [
        Certificates.github
        ])
  ]

  private init() {
    session = Session(serverTrustManager: ServerTrustManager(evaluators: evaluators)
    )
  }

  private static let shared = Network()
  static func request(_ convertible: URLRequestConvertible) -> DataRequest {
    return shared.session.request(convertible)
  }
}
```

i get this error:

```
FAIL serverTrustEvaluationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ServerTrustFailureReason.noRequiredEvaluator(host: "api.github.com"))
2019-12-17 12:03:21.649222-0400 SSLOwner[5533:83111] Task <57DC5433-F132-4453-BB68-CCF90B5F6058>.<1> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -999 [1:89])
```

edit 1: this is my Struct UserList and User

```
import Foundation
struct UserList: Codable {
  let users: [User]

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case users = "items"
  }
}


struct User: Codable {
  let displayName: String

}
```

with

```
session = Session()
```

i get this error:

> responseSerializationFailed(reason:
>   Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.decodingFailed(error:
>   Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary,
>   Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription:
>   "Expected to decode Dictionary but found an array
>   instead.", underlyingError: nil))))

Comment: Rather than `print("FAIL")` which is pretty pointless do `print(error)`

Comment: The error description is *No `ServerTrustEvaluator` was found for the associated host*. I would omit the evaluator

Comment: @vadian can you answer this question please with more details

Comment: I cannot write an answer because I'm guessing. Try a simple session without `ServerTrustManager`

Comment: @vadian i edited my question see please

Answer (score 0):

Your last error says explicitly what is wrong. The response from the API call is an array, and not a dictionary as you assumed. Convert your expected response to a list of users and it should work then:

```
Network.request(Request.users).responseDecodable { (response: AFDataResponse<[User]>) in
  switch response.result {
  case .success(let value):
    print("SUCCESS")
  case .failure(let error):
        print("FAIL")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The root object is an array and there is no object with key `items` so delete `UserList`

Replace

```
AFDataResponse<UserList>)
```

with

```
AFDataResponse<[User]>)
```

And there is also no key `displayName` in the user dictionaries

Replace

```
struct User: Codable {
  let displayName: String
}
```

with

```
struct User: Codable {
  let login: String
}
```